# PHP socket_read/recv blocking python's socket.send

Tags: php, python, sockets, send, recv

I'm building a Firebird DB transaction manager in Python on Linux with JS+PHP clients. Javascript sends all necessary information to PHP; PHP encodes this and sends it via socket to Python, which has a socket bound to a port constantly listening and creates a new thread using threading to handle that request asynchronously.

The accept loop in python:

```
while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    req = conn.recv(1024)
    ret = read_headers(req)

    threading.Thread(target=client_thread, args=(conn, addr, ret, smphr,)).start()
s.close()
```

The send/read block in php:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$sockconnect = socket_connect($sock, $host, $port);
$msg = urldecode(http_build_query($params));
socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));
$received;
while(socket_recv($sock, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1){
    $received .= $buf;
}
echo $received;
socket_close($sock);
```

It all seems to be working properly until we started testing with larger number of connections. I have a loop in the JS client that sends several (25-100 are the numbers I've used so far) queries request with a select first random-number-of-lines from a large table.

**The first few requests that the server receives are processed simultaneously but then it seems to become synchronous.**

After much logging, found out that only 7/8 threads are active at any given time. New requests are only accepted and processed after one of the 7 current ones finishes.

If I comment the socket_recv while loop in php, python will then run everything simultaneously and return as soon as is available, which is exactly what I want, but since I've commented the block that actually gets the result, nothing is shown (obviously).

Every request/queries is logged as a different script call (according to chrome's network dev tool) so I don't know why they're blocking each other.

I'm fairly new at php/python and I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I've also tried different bits of code to read the response in php (none worked as intended):

```
$buf = 'buffer';
socket_recv($sock, $buf, 1024, MSG_WAITALL);
echo $buf;
```

Same as previous implementation, 7/8 thread 'limit'

```
$buf = 'buffer';
socket_recv($sock, $buf, 1024, MSG_DONTWAIT);
echo $buf;
```

As the flag implies, doesn't wait for a response, therefore has no response

```
while ($out = socket_read($sock, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) {
    echo $out;
}
```

Same thread 7/8 thread limit.

Second edit:

Added Python prints, in case it helps.

**With read in php**:

```
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr1
starting select first 1 * from receb_quotas on tr0
starting select first 1 * from receb_quotas on tr2
starting select first 1 * from receb_quotas on tr4
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr3
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr5
finishing tr4 (count: 1) | remaining threads: 7
finishing tr0 (count: 1) | remaining threads: 7
starting select first 150 * from receb_quotas on tr8
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr6
finishing tr2 (count: 1) | remaining threads: 7
starting select first 1 * from receb_quotas on tr7
finishing tr7 (count: 1) | remaining threads: 7
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr9
finishing tr8 (count: 150) | remaining threads: 7
finishing tr1 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 6
finishing tr3 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 5
finishing tr6 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 4
finishing tr5 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 3
finishing tr9 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 2
```

**Without php read**:

```
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr1
starting select first 15 * from receb_quotas on tr0
starting select first 15 * from receb_quotas on tr3
starting select first 3000 * from receb_quotas on tr4
starting select first 1500 * from receb_quotas on tr2
starting select first 150 * from receb_quotas on tr5
starting select first 1 * from receb_quotas on tr6
starting select first 1500 * from receb_quotas on tr7
starting select first 150 * from receb_quotas on tr8
starting select first 15 * from receb_quotas on tr9
finishing tr0 (count: 15) | remaining threads: 11
finishing tr3 (count: 15) | remaining threads: 10
finishing tr6 (count: 1) | remaining threads: 9
finishing tr9 (count: 15) | remaining threads: 8
finishing tr8 (count: 150) | remaining threads: 7
finishing tr5 (count: 150) | remaining threads: 6
finishing tr7 (count: 1500) | remaining threads: 5
finishing tr2 (count: 1500) | remaining threads: 4
finishing tr1 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 3
finishing tr4 (count: 3000) | remaining threads: 2
```

It really does seem that without the read in php, the queries are all started at the same time and returned as soon as ready.

Comment: Can't be sure this is relevant but: What is the `backlog` argument being given to `s.listen`?

Comment: @GilHamilton s.listen is set to 100

Comment: I would put a big fat "sleep forever" in the python sub-thread (`signal.pause()` or `time.sleep(a_large_number)`). Then send, say, 25 or 50 requests. Then try to figure out what state those threads/connections are in. Since you *should* have 25-50 different threads at that point, it may be possible to figure out what's going on. You don't say what platform, but on linux at least, you could launch python with `strace -o /tmp/xxx -ff python <your script>...` and let strace show all the system calls.

Comment: @GilHamilton The python script runs on linux

Comment: K. So I would use `signal.pause`. With the `strace` command, after all requests have been launched (assuming 25 requests), you should have 26 threads (hence 26 files named `/tmp/xxx.NNN`). Look at the last lines in each file. One (the main server thread) should be pending in the `accept` system call, the others should all be pending in `pause`. If not, you may be able to see where they're stuck. (If all 25 *are* now in `pause`, there may be something more subtle going on.)

Comment: @GilHamilton I don't think that's working. I tried and it doesn't log anything. It logs forks and I don't seem to use forks.

Comment: On any recent linux, both process and thread creation invokes the `clone` system call. `strace` should work as I described. Here's a one liner that should prove it: `strace -o /tmp/thr -ff python -c 'import threading, signal; threading.Thread(target=signal.pause).start(); signal.pause()' &` (creates a second thread, then both threads call `pause`). Works with both python2 and python3. Look for trace files named `/tmp/thr.*`

Comment: @GilHamilton Yeah, my bad. Found the trace files but I'm not knowledgable enough in this to make heads or tails of what I'm seeing. I'll try something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Last line of the file is really all you'd need to look at. It should look like `pause(` [without close parenthesis or newline]. If not, then the thread isn't waiting in the `pause` system call.

Comment: @GilHamilton Yeah, the trace files end in pause(

Comment: K. So you are getting multiple threads getting created. Possibly you just have all the incoming connections/thread creations getting (in effect) serialized by competition for processor resources? Also, you might want to read about the https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was a browser issue. Chrome (maybe other modern browsers) only support up to 6 ajax calls at the same time.

Since I had that 7 thread 'cap', one of them being the main thread. This lines up perfectly.